# Why is a scanned pfd page returned in 90 clockwise rotation - when extracting it as an image?

Tags: c#, itext7

I have used iText 7 for transforming a pdf page, that is just an image (from a scanned document) to an image, so that i can process it with ocr. For some pdf files this works very fine, but for others the image "extracted" from it is returned with a 90 degree rotation!

Considering the documents that work fine:
I open word, put in some text and pictures and then convert the file to pdf. When using iText 7 for such files i get the text and images out with no problem at all!

Considering the documents that cause a problem:
I scann a letter and get a pdf file X to my email. X only has an image layer. If i parse X with iText 7 and create a new image from the byte Array i get (using an EventListener for Event type Render_IMAGE), the image is created with a 90 degree rotation???

So for both documents i use the same c# code, but the output is diffrent...

I have used the output image from X (the one with rotation) and converted it to a pdf file. Lets call this Y. So when i create an image from Y again, the new image is not rotated compared to Y! - I just did this for a test, to see if the image will always be rotated or not...

//Implementation for IEventListener:

```
 public void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case EventType.RENDER_IMAGE:
                String filename;
                ImageRenderInfo renderInfo = (ImageRenderInfo)data;
                PdfImageXObject image = renderInfo.GetImage();
                if (image == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                byte[] imageBytes = image.GetImageBytes(true);
                extension = image.IdentifyImageFileExtension();
                filename = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.{2}", path, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), extension);
                images.Add(new ImageStreamObject(imageBytes, filename));
                break;
        }
    }
```

//Class ImageStreamObject

```
public class ImageStreamObject
{
    byte[] image;
    string path;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a data object for storing an image as a byte array and its filepath.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="byteArray"></param>
    /// <param name="filePath"></param>
    public ImageStreamObject(byte[] byteArray, string filePath)
    {
        image = byteArray;
        path = filePath;
    }

    public String GetImagePath()
    {
        return path;
    }
```

//Constructor for the object doing the image "extraction":

```
    public PdfImageExtractor(string filePath, string imageOutputPath)
    {
        pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filePath));
        listener = new ImageRenderListener(imageOutputPath);
        parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(listener);
        imageBuffer = new List<string>();
    }
```

//Method from PdfImageExtractor creating the image files:

```
    public List<string> CreateImagesFromPdfPage(int page)
    {
        FileStream fs;
        byte[] tempImage;
        string tempPath;
        listener.GetImageStreamObjects().Clear();
        parser.ProcessPageContent(pdf.GetPage(page));
        imageStreamObjects = listener.GetImageStreamObjects();
        List<string> pathes = GetImagePathes();
        imageStreamObjects.ForEach(delegate (ImageStreamObject imageStreamObject)
        {
            tempPath = imageStreamObject.GetImagePath();
            tempImage = imageStreamObject.GetImageAsByteArray();
            fs = new FileStream(tempPath, FileMode.Create);
            fs.Write(tempImage, 0, tempImage.Length);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
        });
        return pathes;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitmap image you extract is exactly as it is stored as a resource in the PDF (at least orientation-wise). But whenever a bitmap resource is drawn, it is subject to the current transformation matrix at the time of its drawing, and this current transformation can rotate, skew, translate, and stretch the bitmap considerably.

You can retrieve the value of the current transformation matrix at the time the bitmap is drawn from the `ImageRenderInfo renderInfo` using

```
Matrix ctm = renderInfo.GetImageCtm();
```

and analyze it. Additionally you have to take the page rotation into account which you can retrieve from the page number `page` as

```
int rotation = pdf.GetPage(page).GetRotation()
```

Comment: Thank you for that fast answer! Sorry i reply only now (was very buisy).